A statement about commutativity the projector from the QR decomposition
If a matrix $E = AB \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times r} (r\leq m), A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times r}$, then performing a QR decomposition and resulting in $E = QR$, where $ Q \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times r}$ is a coloumn orthogonal matrix and $Q^{T} Q = I_r \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$.
The orthogonal projection is defined as $QQ^T$, then we have$ QQ^T E = E $. I observe that the orthogonal projection $QQ^{T}$ satisfies:
$$
 QQ^{T} A = A QQ^{T} 
$$.
How should this part be proven? Thx in adavance.
A = rand(10,10);
% generate a positive semidefine matrix
A = A.'*A;
B = rand(10,3);

E = A*B;

[Q,R] = qr(E,0);


Mat1 = Q*Q.'*A;
Mat2 = A*Q*Q.';

tolerance = 1e-14;
% check
are_equal_12 = all(Mat1(:)-Mat2(:)) < tolerance;

% print out the result
if are_equal_12
    disp('The matrix1 and matrix2 are equal within the given tolerance.');
else
    disp('The matrix1 and matrix2 are not equal within the given tolerance.');
end


Your claims are untrue in general. Consider $E=e_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 1}$, and let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ be invertible with $a_{21}\ne 0$, then $B=A^{-1}e_1$. You have $Q=e_1$, $R=1$. Then $QQ^TA = e_1e_1^TA \ne A$ unless $a_{21}=a_{22}=0$. It is also not true that $QQ^TA=AQQ^T$ since this holds only if $a_{12}=a_{21}=a_{22}=0$.
Also $QQ^TB=B$ does not have to hold since $QQ^TB=e_1e_1^TA^{-1}e_1=A^{-1}e_1 = B$ would require that $B_2=0$, i.e. that $(A^{-1})_{21}=0$, but this is also untrue since $(A^{-1})_{21}=-a_{21}/det[A]\ne 0$.
Edit:
I suppose the actual question is why your code suggests the above. I think the answer is that it actually doesn't and you just don't know how to use MATLAB very well. Try this instead:
A = rand(10,10);
% generate a positive semidefine matrix
A = A.'*A;
B = rand(10,3);

E = A*B;

[Q,R] = qr(E,0);


Mat1 = Q*Q.'*A;
Mat2 = A*Q*Q.';

tolerance = 1e-14;
% check
eq = abs(Mat1-Mat2)<tolerance;
are_equal_12 = all(eq,'all');

% print out the result
if are_equal_12
    disp('The matrix1 and matrix2 are equal within the given tolerance.');
else
    disp('The matrix1 and matrix2 are not equal within the given tolerance.');
end


Thank you for your answer! I would like to know further that if A is a positive/negative semi-definite matrix, does the equation : $QQ^{T}A = A QQ^{T}$ holds?

@OwenJun The positive/negative definite setting is a special case of the above. If you mean that $A$ should be allowed to also be singular, that doesn't change things much as I could extend $A$ and $B$ with extra zeroes making $A$ singular but the above argument still applies with minor modifications as far as I can tell. Also your generated $A$ is non-singular with probability $1$ since the subset of matrices with zero determinant has measure zero.

Thank u, this is very useful for me.

In your Matlab code, are_equal_12 = all(eq) returns a vector rather than a scalar; this is probably unintended. I suggest to use abs(Mat1(:)-Mat2(:)) < tolerance instead.

@FedericoPoloni You are correct, thank you for the remark, I fixed it. I wanted to have also the eq matrix so Owen Jun can have a look at it too.

By the way, this is just a problem of clarity / intent / style: the original code works anyway, since Matlab automatically inserts an all when a non-scalar value is used as a truth value. For this reason, the simplest way to write this code would be if eq.

@FedericoPoloni If by the original code you mean Owen Jun's code, then note that it doesn't work as intended because it has all(Mat1(:)-Mat2(:)) and produces a result that states the matrices are equal when they are not, which led them to the above wrong conjecture. If you mean my original code then I guess you are right, although what I really wanted to write originally was all(eq,'all') as edited later on.

I meant the original code in your (lightxbulb's) answer, yes.
